# Is there a way to change ST_asGeoJSON return values?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, postgis-2.0

The function ST_asGeoJSON returns something like:

```
"st_asgeojson":
   {
     "type":"MultiLineString",
     "coordinates":[
        [
          [-3.13512629299993,39.7174353130001],    
          [-19.13510345099996,2.7174767110001]
        ]
      ]
    }
```

And I wonder if there's a way to simplify or customize the JSON it returns, as I only need the coordinates, to something like:

```
{
  coordinates: [
    [-9.13512629299993,38.7174353130001],
    [-9.13510345099996,38.7174767110001]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Be aware that the GeoJSON specification states that

> The GeoJSON object must have a member with the name "type". This member's value is a string that determines the type of the GeoJSON object.

http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#geojson-objects

If you decide that you do not want/need to be compliant with the GeoJSON spec, you can use the `-` (minus) operator as of **postgresql 9.5**.

```
ST_AsGeoJSON(the_geom)::jsonb - 'type'
```

as of **postgres 9.3** you can extract value with `->`

```
ST_AsGeoJSON(the_geom)::json->'coordinates'
```

so you can do some string magic (assuming you still want the coordinates in quotes to stay json compatible)

```
CONCAT('{"coordinates":', ST_AsGeoJSON(the_geom)::json->'coordinates', '}')
```

For **postgres <= 9.2** I think the answer by Michal Zimmermann is the best approach.

---

To reduce the dimensionality of the json output you can use the postgis function `ST_LineMerge` before passing it to `ST_AsGeoJSON`.

```
ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_LineMerge(the_geom))
```

If you have to do this, you should as well consider the impact on MultiLineStrings that actually DO contain multiple linestrings (which is not the case in your example) or if you do not have linestrings with multiple parts (and do not plan to handle such), you should directly save your data as LineString instead of MultiLineString.

Comment: Wow, that is cool SQL. I had no idea you could do that, but then I am still on 9.2, sadly.

Comment: That would be great, I'm using postgreSQL v9.3!

Comment: I added a solution which is compatible with 9.3. I think that using the internal json mechanism is saver than parsing json with string methods. E.g. There is no guarantee that the order of the elements in the json objects stays the way it currently is and that there's no other occurence of a `,` somewhere in the raw json string.

Comment: hmm I tried your alternative for postgres9.3, but I get an `ERROR:  type "jsonb" does not exist`

Comment: Ah sorry, `jsonb` was only introduced in 9.4. It can simply be replaced with `json`.

Comment: but it works with `ST_AsGeoJSON(the_geom)::json->'coordinates'`. One last thing, why it uses an array of an array of arrays `[[[ ]]]` instead of an array of arrays `[[ ]]`

Comment: It's a MultiLineString: the outermost array is the Multi part, the middle one a list of coordinates of every linestring and the most inner one an array of the parts of each coordinates (lat/lon). The most inner one will always have as many elements as the coordinates have dimensions.

Comment: maybe I just need to be a LineString, it's a route between point A and point B

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT concat('{', substring(
    ST_AsGeoJSON(wkb_geometry) from 
    position(',' in ST_AsGeoJSON(wkb_geometry)) + 1
    ))
FROM table_name;
```

It simply finds the first ***,*** character, and extracts the substring from its position to the end of the geojson.

Answer (score 0):

Tiny bit simpler version of Michal Zimmerman's for people on 9.2

Uses regex of the first and last square brackets and returns them and everything in between.

if you really want only the coordinates you could use

```
SELECT substring(ST_AsGeoJSON(wkb_geometry)::json::text, '\\[.*\\]') FROM table_name;
```

This should return just

```
"[[[-3.13512629299993,39.7174353130001], [-19.13510345099996,2.7174767110001]]]"
```

as a string.